# "Connected" vs "disconnected" data model at GAE: how should I proceed in this case?

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

It's better to start with an example to illustrate this case. Let's say we have an `User` class and it should have an list of `Post`.

The first thought is to create this list inside the `User` class, but analyzing the use cases we find out that most of the times we want to retrieve the user without its posts and retrieve the posts without the user. However we need the user ID to retrieve posts. So the other way to create the data model is to not have the associations but create `Post` indexed by `User` ID.

In terms of cost, what are the pros and cons of both implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the billing page, in particular the section on the datastore operations:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

Datastore read costs grow per entity.
Datastore write costs grow per indexed property.

The first method will be much cheaper since it only operates on one User entity, and there's no indexing required.

However, cost probably isn't your sole deciding factor.  Entities are limited to 1MB each, so if you're storing your posts within your User entity, you'll likely run into a wall.  Time to read/write entities also depend on size, so large entities will take longer to read/write.

Comment: In the first method, I will also have one read per `Post` if it's a `OneToMany` relationship (not embedded), right?

Comment: Now I'm confused as to what you're asking.  If you embed the Post object within the User entity, then you only fetch the User entity, but you're limited by your User entity size.  If you're storing the Post as a separate entity, then yes, there is a read op per Post, but that's doing exactly the same thing as the 2nd method.

Comment: I think I got what you just said, just to confirm: if `Post` is an entity (i.e., has a `Key`), and `User` has a `List<Post>`, then it would be N reads if I make `entityManager.find(User.class, userKey).getPosts()` (one for the user and one for each post). Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was assuming you were actually storing a list of Post objects within your User entity.  It sounds like you're asking if the User and Post are both entities, and the User stores a list of keys to the Posts.

The main benefit to the first case (User with a List of keys to Post entities) is that it enables you to fetch Posts in a consistent manner.  After getting the User object, you can read the list of POSTS and fetch them individually.  Datastore get-by-key operations are consistent.  Depending on how you issue the get operations, this may be slower than a query.(ie, if you just use a for loop).

There's a possible very minor other benefit is as long as you don't index your Post List in your User, you can update your User relatively inexpensively this way.  As an extreme example, if your User adds 5 Posts at once, you can add them all to the list, and then write the User once with one write operation.  This isn't really all that great, since you probably have to write your Post entity anyways, But it's one less index write op per entity.

There is still the limit on the size of the User entity, so your List will have a maximum limit.  There's also a maximum on the number of index entries per entity, so if you index the List, that could be a limit (but that would make the User entity more expensive to write too).

From a read perspective, the first case is non optimal.

The second case works better from a read perspective, it makes it easier to get Posts if you have the User id, but you have the index write ops when you write your Post.  If you don't write Posts often, this is better.  Note that queries are eevntually consistent.